# Is the current default SignalR url routing behavior by design?

Tags: asp.net, signalr, url-routing

[The default url for SignalR is /signalr](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#signalrurl)

This actually lets me visit any url which starts in signalr, for example these all work:

- https://localhost:44302/signalr
- https://localhost:44302/signalr/somethingelse
- https://localhost:44302/signalr/somethingelse/hmm
- https://localhost:44302/signalr/hubs
- https://localhost:44302/signalr/somethingelse/hmm/hubs

This is very useful, because I can add extra information in the url which is opaque to SignalR but can used in an upstream proxy (HAProxy) to route on (to different web servers).

A typical use case for me is:

- https://localhost:44302/signalr/customerA/production
- https://localhost:44302/signalr/customerA/stage
- https://localhost:44302/signalr/customerB/production
- https://localhost:44302/signalr/customerB/stage

Can I depend on this behavior (it's been the same from 0.5 to 2.2)?

Update:

I found the issue "[Route matching for the Owin hub dispatcher handler is too agressive](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/1445)" in the SignalR repo on GitHub. This is "closed" but I still don't know if this behavior is by design, or if it might change in future. I want to take a dependency on this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't, the proxy url is generated on the fly, so if something goes wrong with your application and the proxy is not created the rest of the url is not likely to exist. The way around this is to manually generate the proxy yourself and use it instead, then you do not have the risk.

Comment: This is not what I meant - do you think I should reword the question?

Comment: It would help, I am not sure I understand what you are asking.